# Set string foreign key is not working in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm setting string attribute as primary key, and now I want to make the relationships between 2 table. I wish to declare string foreign key in another table to make sure these two tables are connected. But I'm getting an error when I want to migrate the tables

**Countries**

```php
Schema::create('countries', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('country_name')->unique();
    $table->primary('country_name');
    $table->string('country_img');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Destinations**

```php
Schema::create('destinations', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('dest_id');
    $table->string('dest_name');
    $table->integer('dest_budget');
    $table->double('dest_hrs');
    $table->string('dest_country')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('dest_country')->references('country_name')->on('countries');
    $table->string('dest_state');
    $table->string('dest_address');
    $table->string('lat');
    $table->string('lng');
    $table->string('dest_info');
    $table->string('dest_ctgr');
    $table->string('dest_img');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Country model**

```php
protected $primaryKey = 'country_name';
public $incrementing = false;
protected $fillable = ['country_name', 'country_img'];

public function destinasi(){

    return $this->hasMany(Destination::class);
}
```

**Destination model**

```
protected $primaryKey = 'dest_id';
protected $fillable = ['dest_name','dest_address','lat','lng','dest_ctgr','dest_budget','dest_hrs','dest_country','dest_state','dest_info','dest_img'];

public function country() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Country::class);
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax

I think that the way I write the foreign key is wrong and makes this error appeared.

Comment: Try replacing `Country::class` and `Destination::class` with a string: `'App\Destination'`, `'App\Country'`

Comment: Why is this unsigned? `$table->string('dest_country')->unsigned();`. Try removing the `unsigned()` part.

Answer (score 2):

In your Destinations schema

replace

`$table->foreign('dest_country')->references('country_name')->on('countries')`;

with

`$table->string('dest_country');`

And in your model

```
public function country(){

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Country', 'dest_country');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You only specify foreign key, only after column creation, so your migration should be

```
Schema::create('destinations', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('dest_id');
        $table->string('dest_name');
        $table->integer('dest_budget');
        $table->double('dest_hrs');
        $table->string('dest_country');
        $table->string('dest_country');
        $table->string('dest_state');
        $table->string('dest_address');
        $table->string('lat');
        $table->string('lng');
        $table->string('dest_info');
        $table->string('dest_ctgr');
        $table->string('dest_img');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('dest_country')->references('country_name')->on('countries')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');;
    });
```

refer [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)